# Using while loop in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am comfortable to write a code with a for loop, but I am not that comfortable to write a code with while loop. Below you can see a for loop which gives me the value for i_0, but could someone show me how to find the value for i_0 with a while loop? :)

```
    // Find index of x value closest to zero:
  int i_0 = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < npts; i++){     
        if(abs(x_array[i]) < abs(x_array[i_0])){
          i_0 = i;
        }
      }
```

Comment: The fact you can comfortably write a for-loop but not a while-loop make me doubt you don't fully understand how the for-loop works.

Comment: Technically, `while(condition)` is the same as `for( ; condition; )`. and can be used when there is nothing for the 1st and 3rd part of the `for`. No magic involved.

Comment: Unless you're getting into iterators and such, what you're describing and asking is the same in C.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < npts)
{
    if (abs(x_array[i]) < abs(x_array[i_0])) {
        i_0 = i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

You may also wrap the loop around a scope to ensure that variable `i` is disposed after the loop:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < npts)
    {
        if (abs(x_array[i]) < abs(x_array[i_0])) {
            i_0 = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that i++ updates I to 1,2,3 etc.?

Comment: @Ivan That's right.

Comment: Your second example is an infinite loop and would soon segfault on an invalid array index

Comment: @lurker Oh I'm sorry, I have replaced `true` with `i < npts` now.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you can comfortably write a for-loop but not a while-loop suggest that you don't fully understand how the for-loop works. If that's the case, here's how the for-loop works:
[image: for(some declaration to execute before the loop; condition to check before each iteration; expression to execute after each iteration){expression to run during each iteration}]

And here's how a while-loop works:
[image: while(condition to check before each iteration){expression to run during each iteration}]

So to translate a for-loop into a while-loop, you just have to figure how to put the `some declaration to execute before the loop` and `expression to execute after each iteration` in the while-loop structure:
[image: some declaration to execute before the loop; while(condition to check before each iteration){expression to run during each iteration; expression to execute after each iteration}]